# Space between start and end of axis

Tags: chart.js

I try to display values on a chart and use the datalabels-plugin.
I have a lot of different line charts with multiple values. Most of these have a probleme. The datalbaels are hidden.
How can I add space on the top Yaxis and start Xaxis to fix this ?

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ["","1989", "2004", "2014", "2017", "2019", ""],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Valorisation',
                        data: ["null",{{{cote_1989_eu}}}, {{{cote_2004}}}, {{{cote_2014}}}, {{{cote_2017}}}, {{{cote_2017}}}, "null"],
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 178, 0)',
                        borderWidth: 5,
                        pointHitRadius: 100
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        datalabels: {
                            backgroundColor: '#ffa100',
                            padding: 8,
                            borderRadius: 6,
                                clip: true,
                                    color: 'white',
                                        font: {
                                weight: 'bold'
                            },
                            align: 'center',
                            offset: 10,
                            formatter: function(value) {
                                return value.toLocaleString() + ' €';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                    return value.toLocaleString() + ' €';
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

[image]

EDIT: The problem with the xaxis is solverd, and kind of for the start of Yaxis.
The problem of the top of Yaxis is still here !

Comment: Can you post your sample data? It would make it faster to solve your issue.

Comment: I just did it ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to set `offset` to `true` on the `xAxis` and `max` value on the `yAxis`'s ticks configuration.

```
const data = [100036, 140000, 400000, 900000, 1000000, null];
var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        offset: true
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          max: Math.max(...data) * 1.2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Taken from the [official docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html?h=max):

- If `offset` is `true`, extra space is added to the both edges and the axis is scaled
  to fit into the chart area.
- As for `max`, setting it will override the maximum number for the scale which by default is derived from the maximum value of the data set.

---

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
const data = [100036, 140000, 400000, 900000, 1000000, null];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["1989", "2004", "2014", "2017", "2019", ""],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Valorisation",
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 178, 0)",
        borderWidth: 5,
        pointHitRadius: 100
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        backgroundColor: "#ffa100",
        padding: 8,
        borderRadius: 6,
        clip: true,
        color: "white",
        font: {
          weight: "bold"
        },
        align: "center",
        offset: 10,
        formatter: function(value) {
          return value.toLocaleString() + " €";
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          offset: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            max: Math.max(...data) * 1.2,
            callback: function(value, inde0x, values) {
              return value.toLocaleString() + " €";
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.5.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Tank you very much, it worked for my example. But now, when a value is missing in other charts (I don't have it in my database for a particular model), the line doesn't show at all. Is there a solution ?

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce that, can you create a fiddle or a pen with that data set.

Comment: In this example, it works because I wrote the datalabels myself. But I use a mongodb database in reality and when I display a null value, the chart crashes like this (I know there is two "," in the data variable): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXZbzN

Comment: I think it's because spread operator doesn't work with null. But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Yup, the extra `,` was the one causing the crash. The spread operator would still work with `null` values, try console logging it. And chartjs would not display any points for `null` values so in your new dataset, displaying only 2 values is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Ok, when I console logging it, the null values are replaced by empty. When I remove your solution (max: Math.max(...data) * 1.2,), it displays even th null value. I don't understand.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong cause I can't replicate it on my side, see here: https://codepen.io/analizapandac/pen/MZQbNM. Sorry I can't be of much help with this.